# Auto Resizing of the tableView Cells is not working with multiline labels in its contentView

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8, xcode6, ios-simulator

I have tableviewController with custom cell. In each cell I want to display multi-line labels. So, I added these labels to content view of the cell and set all the constraints.

The cells should resize automatically according to height of the multi-line labels.But the labels are overflowing the cells without the cell height being changed.Initially tried with following code in view did load of tableView Controller

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

I was not successful. I have even referred some of the tutorials, but no use. I am creating everything programatically in my app. There is no involvement of storyBoard in case of this tableView Controller

Comment: just add label.numberOfLines = 0

Comment: did that way back. Thank you !! I forgot to set bottom layout constraints for contentView, that was the issue.